# How do I copy/paste to a VM console window in the VMware ESXi HTML interface?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, console, copy, html

I have an Ubuntu VM in an instance of VMware ESXi 6.7.0. I am using Chrome to access the VM console in the HTML interface of VMware ESXi. (I do not have SSH access to the VM.)

I would like to copy/paste from my Windows PC to the VM console window. I found an [article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/57122) describing how to enable copy/paste, so I followed the steps.

As you can see, I have VMware Tools installed on the VM:
[image]

I also added the `isolation.tools.copy.disable`, `isolation.tools.paste.disable`, and `isolation.tools.setGUIOptions.enable` configuration parameters to the Advanced settings of the VM:
[image]

After I powered on the VM and copied some text in Windows, I do not have the option to paste in the VM console window:
[image]

Comment: You need to use the VMRC to connect to the VM console, not the browser console.

Comment: I guess there's no way to copy/paste in the browser console?

Comment: What does the article say?

Comment: It makes no mention of whether or not it is possible to copy/paste in the browser console.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. You need to use the VMRC.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML console is not meant for getting any real work done, it is more suited for checking if a VM has stalled, or is stuck in some reboot loop.

For functionality like copy and paste to work, you need to use either the VMware Remote Console (VMRC) or VMware Workstation Pro, which includes VMRC functionality.

You still need to set the following 3 options:

```
isolation.tools.copy.disable = FALSE
isolation.tools.paste.disable = FALSE
isolation.tools.setGUIOptions.enable = TRUE
```

Comment: I've installed VMRC but still don't have copy & paste capabilities. Are the `isolation.tools`  config parameters shown in the question also a requirement on top of using the VMRC?

Comment: Setting the (3) isolation.tools config options was indeed needed, on top of using VMRC console for Esxi 7.0 to enable copy/paste function. It is a bit dodgy/slow to register the operations, but finally works!